# PNP Powershell how to use Add-PnPField -type user to set to users only

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I'm reasonably new to PowerShell and have created a script to deploy a list into SharePoint using PNP PowerShell. One of the list items is a user field that is created with the following line

```
Add-PnPField -List "Owners" -DisplayName "Owner" -InternalName Owner -Type User -Required -ErrorAction Continue -AddToDefaultView | Out-Null
```

Can anyone tell me how I set this field to be users only and not users & groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible via the `Add-PnPField` command, so what you can do is use `Add-PnPField` to add the field first and then use `Set-PnPField` to modify the field to make it `PeopleOnly`.

You can do that as below:

```
$field = Add-PnPField -List "Owners" -DisplayName "Owner" -InternalName Owner -Type User -Required -ErrorAction Continue -AddToDefaultView | Out-Null

Set-PnPField -List "Owners" -Identity $field.Id -Values @{"SelectionMode"=0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Gautam I was getting an error because $field was null but i fixed it by adding a line to get the id of the owner column between the two $field = Get-PnPField -List "Owners" -Identity "Owner"